# How do you set vimrc to run a command on startup, only if one window is being opened?

Tags: vimrc

I want vim to open Tagbar with `:TagbarToggle` when vim is starting up, but only:

- If the file is Python
- If it's not vimdiff
- If I'm not using `vim -O file1.py file2.py` to open multiple windows

I would expect this to work:

```
if ! &diff && winnr('$') == 1    
    autocmd FileType python :TagbarToggle
endif
```

Especially since `:echo winnr('$')` in vim does show the number of windows currently open, but adding `echo winnr('$')` to vimrc always returns 1, even if multiple windows are being opened with `vim -O`.

Is there a different way to check in vimrc if multiple windows are being opened?

I'm pretty sure I can hack together a solution based on timers (`timer_start`), where it waits for vim to open a hard-coded amount of time before checking `winnr('$')`, but that seems dumb. On slower systems, like a raspberry pi (which I use), the hardcoded value would need to be longer to adjust for longer startup time, but a longer timer on a faster system would be noticeable (the files would open, and half a second later, tagbar would open, which is annoying).

Comment: Maybe put the checks in `autocmd VimEnter python if (...) | :TagbarToggle | endif`.. is what I'm thinking but that's off the top of my noodle.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [VimEnter](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#VimEnter) auto-command, which only runs at Vim initialization, but *after* it has loaded all plug-ins and opened all buffers.

I just tested this combination below. It behaves the way you describe your requirements for the specific use cases you mentioned.

```
autocmd VimEnter * ++once if !&diff && winnr('$') == 1 && &filetype ==# 'python' | execute 'TagbarToggle' | endif
```

As suggested by @Matt, we can check for `bufnr('$') == 1` instead of `winnr('$') == 1` to also cover the case you're opening multiple files in separate tabs with `vim -p` (but maybe you *do* want to toggle the tagbar in that case?) I also updated my answer to include a `++once` modifier on the `autocmd`, to avoid accumulating multiple copies of the `autocmd` when you reload your vimrc (source it again.)

As pointed out by @B.Layer, it might be possible to use a match for `*.py` on the `VimEnter` event, so you could use `autocmd VimEnter *.py` and skip the check for `&filetype ==# 'python'`

The `:execute` in the call to `:TagbarToggle` is to prevent that user-defined command to take the `|` as an argument. By default, user-defined commands take the bar as an argument, unless they've been carefully defined to allow it as a separator. Using `:execute` to call it is the standard way to work around this issue.

Comment: `*.py`? And why `execute` rather than just `TagbarToggle`?

Comment: Checking `bufnr('$') == 1` instead of `winnr` also allows for `-p` option. `++once` is always a right thing to put after `VimEnter`.

Comment: @BLayer regarding `*.py`, I'm not sure what the event looks like for VimEnter. I haven't looked, but I don't think it's related to the files opened, since the autocmd runs even if you open no files, or multiple files... `exe 'TagbarToggle'` is to be safe from commands defined without `-bar` (unfortunately the `-bar` behavior is not the default one), in which case `:exe` is required. I haven't checked whether `TagbarToggle` is defined without `-bar`, but using `exe` is guaranteed to work, so I included that.

Comment: BTW, the objects/events/etc. matched by the autocmd patterns are often not clear to me. Other than Buf* and FileType, it's hard to figure out what they'll be... The docs are not super helpful here either (as far as I remember.) Probably a great topic for a question here.

Comment: My response was going to be "It's a toggle, i.e. no args, so put anything you want after it" but tested it and the silly thing needs `-bar` for `-nargs=0` commands. What ever for I don't know.

Comment: As for `*.py` it works fine with VimEnter...but agree that docs could be better.